# What is the value of the redirecting the .ca domain to the .com for a site serving the USA and Canada?

Tags: url, top-level-domains

Lets say that there is a population of Canadians who don't know about a example.com.  Thy are instructed to go visit the website: "example".   If only `example.com` is registered, and not `example.ca`:

1. What percentage of those Canadians will assume a .ca TLD?
2. Of those, how many of them will be "lost visitors" because they were confused by a website that is (a) non-existent or (b) redirecting to a competitor and couldn't figure it out?
3. Of those "lost visitors" who couldn't even figure out the URL, how many would've been able to actually use the website without someone holding their hand every step of the way? I.e. do we even want these users in the first place? (Struggling to word this question in a more neutral tone)

Comment: It sounds like your main site is the `.com` and you are asking about how many people from Canada would type in the `.ca` address instead?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, only the .com is currently registered, and no one owns the .ca, though someone could buy it in the future.

Comment: I replaced your example with "example.com", I've never seen Google used as example domain before and I was getting confused.

Comment: I am not sure this question can be answered with anything other than an opinion or at least a guess.

Comment: @closetnoc That was my assumption as well, but I hope there's some quantifiable or even anecdotal answer, ex. if someone bought their .ca domain and saw a correlated increase in profits originating from Canadian visitors, all else being equal